# Rule-based styling window freeze in QGIS 2.18.16-22

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18, rule-based

While I was working on cartographic files (QGIS 2.18.16 - Linux Mint 18.1) using the rule-based styling window, suddenly the window and the program freeze and I can not longer work on editing. By closing and reopening the project file (and also other analogues other than those on which I was working) the problem remains (if i try work with the rule-based styling) even after uninstalling and reinstalling QGIS updating it to version 2.18.22.
Opening the same files with version 3.2 the problem does not seem to exist.
I would like to continue using version 2.18.x ltr up to the next 3.4 ltr, can this problem be overcome? Can it depend on the existence of a cache related to the rule-based styling window that is no longer accessible?

I add some informations: 1-it seems that the block occurs only when the rule-based styling window is open 2-the files I've worked on are on an external USB hdd 3-coinciding with this problem I detected the unwanted creation of a second mount point for the external USB hdd while the previous one was not accessible and with the root owner 4-also restoring the mount point setting as before the problem remain

Update 2018-28-07: I found that this problem was already reported as a bug here: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16778
but I did not understand if it was taken into consideration or if we need to propose it again.

Comment: Any rulebased styling, or specific data and/or rulings?

Comment: I tested with two different qgis project files based on different .shp datasets (i.e. if i open the rule-based styling windows and try to add and/or modify a rule the window and qgis itself freeze.

Comment: What do you mean by "other analogues other than those on which I was working"? Do you have more than one QGIS project open at a time?

Comment: Sorry for my English, I mean that the same problem also occurs with files other than those on which I was working the first time it occurred (for this I do not think it is a problem of file corruption)

Answer (score 1):

I Just Had The same problem on QGIS 2.18.24, eventually I succeeded creating Ruled Based Styling by editing the style through the 'label toolbar', via 'Layer Labeling Options' button (instead of opening the style from the Layers Panel Properties).